# Halakha book for modern working place

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, jewish-books, employment, modern-times

Is there a halakha book providing the guidance rules for proper behavior at a modern working place? I mean not only relatively obvious "halakhot yekhud" or "kashrut" but taking into consideration intricacies of modern cubicle world. For example:

- Halakhic view on criticizing manager or other employees at meeting?
- Is it good to report the failures of the manager to the manager above him?
- Is it possible to give unrealistic schedules if my job security is in danger in case I say the truth?
- Is it good to hire people while company is trouble...

etc...

Comment: Boris, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for this question, whose answer many of us could possibly find very useful! I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: Perhaps this link would be useful. http://www.darchenoam.org/ethics/pe_home.htm

Comment: There is a book called [9:00 to 5:00](http://levinejudaica.com/catalog/product_info.php?cPath=0_35_957_1037&products_id=7161) by Rabbi Shmuel Neiman. It is focused on gender relations and is quite restrictive. I'm not going to cite it as an answer since it doesn't focus on the ethical as per the question, but I feel like it bears mentioning in this context.

Comment: @l' great! now just cite the seif where each of the bullet points is mentioned. :}

Answer (score 6):

The book [Making it Work](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1680250310) was released by Rabbi Ari Wasserman which contains discussions of many Halachic questions that arise in the modern workplace. The description is as follows:

> The modern day workplace presents Jewish men and women with a constant array of obvious as well as subtle challenges, and now there is this go-to-guide for practical halachic solutions!
>
> From business meetings in non-kosher restaurants, shaking hands with the opposite gender, wearing a kippah, social gatherings and holiday parties...to yichud, personal use of office supplies, finding time to learn, daven minchah, and so much more this comprehensive title covers it all.
>
> Filled with halachah, mussar, hashkafah, and true stories, this engaging, user-friendly guide is essential for anyone involved in today s complex business world.

Although the book does discuss the "relatively obvious" problems of Kashrus and Yichud, it also discusses more nuanced choshen mishpat questions that arise in the corporate world. Rabbi Wasserman himself has significant experience working in the corporate world.
Additionally, he has shiurim on these topics available on his [website](https://www.workplacehalacha.com).

Comment: This is wonderful book - and there is a woman-specific version that just came out, also highly recommended (disclosure: I read a pre-version and suggested a number of additions): [Making It All Work: Women Surviving and Thriving at Work](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/1680254081/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_U_BBT7Cb77MPRF7)

Answer (score 4):

[The Ethical Imperative](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/ethh.html) is available from Artscroll and includes more than 60 essays on Torah ethics and values, written by Rabbinic authorities including Rabbi Shimon Schwab, zt"l, Rabbi Yaakov Ruderman, zt"l, Rav Avrohom Pam, zt'l, and the Bostoner Rebbe, zt'l. Other contributors include well-known scholars, writers and lecturers such as Rabbi Berel Wein, Rabbi Yissocher Frand, Rabbi Yisroel Reisman, Professor Aaron Twerski, Dr. Judith Bleich and Rabbi Nosson Scherman.