# Sefer on Contemporary Shailos

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, jewish-books, shulchan-aruch, english

Would anyone know a *sefer* on *Contemporary Halachic Shailos* (=questions) in English (on all of *Shulchan Aruch*?)

Comment: More specific: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22559 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15407

Comment: You might want to look into the Gray Matter series by Rabbi Chaim Jachter.

Comment: Otzar Hatshuvos by Rabbi Abraham Scheinberg is very good.

Comment: Perhaps your best bet is the English ed. of Abraham S. Abraham's Nishmat Avraham.

Comment: @mevaqesh Nishmat Avraham is medical halacha only I believe

Comment: @mbloch it is focused on medical issues, but it goes through all 4 parts of shulchan aruch. Inevitably a tremendous volume of practical and contemporary halacha questions are presented in English.

Comment: @mevaqesh wanted to thank you for the reference to Nishmat Avraham. I now bought them and studied dozens of pages. It is truly excellent and I had mis estimated how relevant it would be also for non-doctors. It is extremely pedagogical and brings first-hand rulings from R SZAuerbach, R Eliashiv, etc. which are not found elsewhere. I will update the answer below with renewed thanks

Comment: @mbloch You are very welcome. I am glad you enjoyed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many series of such books, a few I like are

- R Daniel Mann from Eretz Hemda has a very nice series called [Living the halachic process](http://www.eretzhemdah.org/publications.asp?lang=en&pageid=30&cat=5) (also available [one of them also available on Kindle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003Y5HDJY)) - you can sample some online [as part of the OU Vebbe Rebbe series](https://www.ouisrael.org/torah-tidbits/vebbe-rebbe-1001/) *(I cannot find the table of contents, try varying the number in the URL)*
- R Ari Enkin has another [very nice series of halakhic insights and responsa](http://rabbienkin.com/bookstore/) - you can sample some online [here](http://www.torahmusings.com/author/arienkin/)
- R Abraham's [Nishmat Avraham](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwic2srHg6_KAhUG7g4KHXWEDnwQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.artscroll.com%2FBooks%2F9781578195756.html&usg=AFQjCNGddowgmxsijt63tGukCjFjBw8Qbg&sig2=s5udv2fQlF_83z6krqnVkw) is a compendium of medical halachot following the 4 orders of the Shulchan Aruch, it is extremely pedagogical (h/t mevaqesh for the reference) (3 volumes)
- R Chaim Jachter: [Gray matter](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=dp_byline_sr_book_1?ie=UTF8&text=Rabbi%20Chaim%20Jachter&search-alias=books&field-author=Rabbi%20Chaim%20Jachter&sort=relevancerank) (4 volumes)
- R J David Bleich's older series of [Contemporary Halachic problems](http://www.amazon.com/J.-David-Bleich/e/B001KMJWF6/ref=dp_byline_cont_book_1) (at least 6 volumes)
- R J. Simcha Cohen: [How does Jewish law work](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=How%20does%20Jewish%20law%20work) (2 volumes, older)

The first three are my preferred by far, they are highly readable, very diverse (matching your question of "all of SA") and the issues adressed are very relevant.